# Error installing CiviCRM on GoDaddy-Hosted Wordpress Website

Tags: wordpress

I am getting a database error when installing CiviCRM on a WordPress website hosted by Go Daddy.  The error is: 'Could Not Create a Database Trigger.' I've seen several online posts about Go Daddy not permitting the use of triggers on MySQL 5.0.  Is this still in effect?  Is there a work-around?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is "[yes](https://www.godaddy.com/help/do-you-restrict-any-features-in-mysql-4150-2400)", and "no".

I would strongly discourage using GoDaddy shared hosting (or almost any shared hosting) when running CiviCRM for any non-trivial use.  It's going to be slooow and possibly non-functional (as in your case).